# How to configure jetty request.log date format?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

Can someone advise, I have an issue with *request.log* on some of my *jetty* instances.
It looks like the date in the log record is locale dependent, for example below it is formatted like russian locale which means 18 of February, despite the fact that the system locale on this RHEL 6.6 + Jetty 9.2.1 instance is set to en_US.UTF-8.

```
10.1.182.45 -  -  [18/фев/2017:16:17:11 +0200] "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.0"
10.1.182.45 -  -  [18/фев/2017:16:17:23 +0200] "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.0"    
10.1.182.45 -  -  [18/фев/2017:16:17:59 +0200] "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.0"
```

I would like to change format to "18/Feb/2017" because on other similar instances it is in English and I can't determine which factor affects this.

I didn't find such option in the jetty configuration files for request.log, there was only the time zone setting, and the system locale is already in en_US.UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NCSA Log has a Locale, and its using the Java [`Locale.getDefaults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) to figure it out for your system.

```java
Locale logLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

As for how to change it, you can either ...

- Setup your default Java Locale to be more appropriate for all things running in your Java JVM.
- Or, in your chosen NCSA Log configuration, you can use the [`.setLogLocale(Locale)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.html#setLogLocale-java.util.Locale-) to set Locale you want it to use.